# Import and Export Excel file from the vue

Tags: json, excel, vuejs2

I am fetching data from the backend it comes in JSON format, so I will like to download that data as the excel file. And I also need to create an import button so that I can upload the excel file and file data can be in the JSON format in the Vue, so it is easy to process.

So is there any best library that can be used from which I can do both the above process (JSON to EXCEL for export and EXCEL to JSON for import)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the conversion on the backend side.

When user uploads Excel file, you convert it to JSON and display in Vue. Likewise, when user wants to "export" JSON from page, you do the conversion (from JSON to Excel) on backend.

Without knowing your use-case and backend technology, there isn't much more to say about that.

But, if you're really pressed on doing it on client side, take a look at [SheetJS](https://github.com/sheetjs/sheetjs). And here is a pretty straightforward [tutorial](https://javacodepoint.com/convert-excel-file-data-to-json-in-javascript/) on how to do it.